# error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to call a window using the following code

```
self.Modality = [[Modalities alloc]initWithNibName:@"Modalities" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:self.Modality animated:YES];
```

where modality is object of modalities (class)

I get the following errors

error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found
error: accessing unknown 'Modality' getter method

any suggestion to solve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare you **Modality** property as `nonatomic` `retain` but not `readonly`.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* Modality;
```

And use below in your .m files

```
@synthesize Modality;
```

Comment: it worked but it give another error  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIStatusBarOrientationAnimationParameters count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe3c830'

Comment: @AMH : you are calling method "count" with the object which does'nt implement the "count" method  , just do a cross check ..

Comment: I have nsaray the application crash at  return [ModalitiesArray count] ; I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are refining your code of your [previous question](http://@property%20%28nonatomic,%20retain%29%20NSArray%20%2a%20Modalities%20;) you've already set up the property correctly. I think you forgot to synthesize the accessor methods, add a

```
@synthesize Modality;
```

After

```
@implementation ...
```

**NOTE**

You should not begin the names your variables with a capital letter. It's common practice to use this for class names.